# Moving IBOutlet views

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following situation.

- I have the following views in storyboard: lifetimeView, monthlyView, yearlyView. Based on an A/B test, I want to hide the lifetimeView and monthlyView, and move the yearly view where the monthlyView is.

  ```
        self.priceYearly.text = "$19.99"
        self.monthlyView.isHidden = true
        self.lifetimeView.isHidden = true
        self.yearlyView.frame = self.monthlyView.frame
        self.benefitsView.frame = self.lifetimeView.frame
  ```

This code does not move the yearlyView or the benefitsView though. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Are they one above the other, or in a "grid"? What about using a UICollectionView (if it's a simple grid), or maybe a UIStackView? If you use constraints, then changing only the frame might not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are severals ways to handle this.

Trying to manipulate the frames of your views is not one of those ways however. (Auto-layout generally ignores changes you make to the frame rectangles of the views it manages, and instead calculates new frames based on its constraints.)

It is possible to set up constraints for your views so that they shift over when you collapse one to zero size, but that is a bit of a pain.

Instead I would suggest using a stack view. Stack views are smart enough to close up the gap when you hide one of their subviews, and make room when you un-hide a view.